# Hesitation in animation with jQuery slideToggle

Tags: jquery, jquery-effects, jquery-slide-effects

I am trying to do a simple jQuery `slideToggle()` on a DIV containing text and have found the animation to be very sluggish (seems to hesitate) as the `slideDown` animation nears the bottom of the sliding DIV.

Code and example of this may be found [here](http://opheliadesign.com/dev/toggle-slide.html). I have tested on several computers and all modern versions of the popular browsers, all behave the same way. Strangely, when I run the exact same page in [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/A4run/), it is smooth.

Any ideas?

**UPDATE**

Part of this seems to be, like someone else suggested, that jQuery does not know the height of the sliding DIV before the animation runs. Since the content in the sliding DIV will be dynamic and either very short or somewhat long, neither do I. So, I tried grabbing the height of the DIV prior to hiding it with jQuery and then setting the CSS height accordingly. Made for a somewhat smoother animation but probably not the best solution - [demo](http://opheliadesign.com/dev/toggle-slide-2.html)

**UPDATE 2**

It would appear that the problem was due to several CSS issues with the initial example. First, way too many DIVs. Second, the sliding DIV had padding set - does not play well 
with `toggleSlide`, and finally, the sliding DIV was in a container DIV that also contained the `#control-container` (button) DIV.

Reducing the DIVs down to two (outer DIV for the sliding element and the sliding DIV itself) and not setting the outer sliding DIV padding seemed to do the trick - [final example](http://opheliadesign.com/dev/toggle-slide-3.html).

Comment: Which browser are you seeing the issue? Only thing I can think of, is to add an easing function.

Comment: I'm on My iPhone right now so I can't verify my assumption - but I have encountered similar quirks before when animating elements with `padding` and/or `margin` properties and `height:auto`. Try wrapping your actual content into a container div and/or giving it a fixed height to see whether the animation runs smoothly then.

Comment: IE 9, latest versions of Chrome and Firefox. The thing that has me the most puzzled is that it runs flawlessly in jsFiddle

Comment: It jumps for me in both the JSFiddle and your example. I'm using Chromium 17.

Comment: change fast to slow in jsfiddle and you can see its jumps

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Blatant Karmaw*****g just in case I'm on the right track ;)

---

I'm on My iPhone right now so I can't verify my assumption - but I have encountered similar quirks before when animating elements with `padding` and/or `margin` properties and `height:auto`.

jQuery seems to have a hard time determining the actual height before animating under these circumstances.

Try wrapping your actual content into a container div and/or giving it a fixed height to see whether the animation runs smoothly then.

---

*Edit 1:*

Another workaround I remember using:

- Do not hide the element via CSS
- On domready, determine element's height via jQuery and assign it to the element via `data()`, then set element's `height` to `0` and `overflow:hidden`
- Instead of `slideToggle()`, use `animate()` with the height saved before.

Fugly, but does the trick.

---

*Edit 2*:

A related issue (and a workaround) [are described here](http://jqueryfordesigners.com/animation-jump-quick-tip/)

---

*Edit 3*:

Does [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RHyw4/) work for you, by any chance? Added Container with padding - excuse the bad formatting, jsfiddle's no fun on the iPhone.

Comment: LOL, was heading down a similar path before you edited.. see my new link.. thanks! Trying this now

Comment: Actually, I've never used `data` before - could you give me an example for this type of situation?

Comment: Setting data: `$('#someid').data('actualheight', $('#someid').innerHeight());` Reading data: `var targetheight = $('#someid').data('actualheight');`

Comment: Just had a massive lightning storm roll through the area, back to fiddling.. Edit 3 looks about the same, trying out the other suggestion (Edit 1)

Comment: Got me on the right track, thanks! See edits - looks pretty smooth now

Answer (score -1):

The jQuery Easing plugin may help.